# How to get setInterval countdown working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble getting this countdown working. How do I get it to count down?

also if I wanted to get it to count up, how would I go about doing that?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vx16tnet/2/

jquery:

```
$('.count').on('click', function(){
    var countDown = $('.count').text();
    console.log(countDown);

    setInterval(function() {
        countDown--;
        $('.count').html(countDown);
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Your code in your question does not match your fiddle. Can you resolve this?

Comment: Honestly, would do it a bit easier.  Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/vx16tnet/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to decrement the float number `1.523` by `0.001` every `1` second.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/vx16tnet/3/)

```
function myfunction() {

    setInterval(function(){
        var current = $('.number').text();
        console.log('the value is ' + current);
        var newNumb = Math.round((parseFloat(current) - 0.001) * 1000) / 1000;
        $('.number').html(newNumb);
        console.log(newNumb);
    }, 1000);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    myfunction();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.count').on('click', function() {
  var count = $(this);
  var countDown = parseInt(count.text()) || 0;
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (!countDown) {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
    count.text(countDown--);
  }, 50);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="count" title="Click to start">10</span>
<span class="count" title="Click to start">100</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Call setinterval on the myfunction() instead of within it

```
function myfunction() {
    var current = $('.number').text();
        console.log('the value is ' + current);

       var newNumb = parseFloat(current) + 1;

        $('.number').html(newNumb);
        console.log(newNumb);

}
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){ myfunction();}, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

count Down:
    var clock = 10;

```
var countdownId = 0;



function start() {

    //Start clock

    countdownId = setInterval("countdown()", 1000);

}



function countup(){

    if(clock > 0){

        clock = clock+ 1;

        document.getElementById('cdDiv').innerHTML = clock;

    }

else {

    //Stop clock

        clearInterval(countdownId);

}
```

function countdown(){

```
    if(clock > 0){

        clock = clock - 1;

        document.getElementById('cdDiv').innerHTML = clock;

    }

else {

    //Stop clock

        clearInterval(countdownId);

}
}
```